# What is the difference between eof(), fail(), bad(), and good() in C++ streams?

Tags: c++, c++11, io

I am currently learning C++ from the C++ Primer 5th edition. I am confused about the behavior of the methods to check the status of a stream due to seemingly conflicting information. On page 312 it states

> If any of `badbit`, `failbit`, or `eofbit` are set, then a condition
>   that evaluates that stream will fail.

On the very next page, it says that `s.fail()` is

> true if `failbit` or `badbit` in the stream is set

and that

> the code that is executed when we use a stream as a condition is
>   equivalent to calling `!fail()`.

This doesn't make sense because any expression that uses `fail()` should only know about `failbit` and `badbit` (since those are what make up `fail()`'s value) and yet `!fail()` is equivalent to all *three* of `badbit`, `failbit`, and `eofbit` being false.

How do these seemingly contradictory statements fit together?

Comment: See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate. It provides an excellent overview of the topic.

Comment: "a condition is equivalent to calling !fail()." It isn't. Did the book say otherwise?

Comment: @n.m. I am quoting [C++ Primer](https://www.amazon.com/Primer-5th-Stanley-B-Lippman/dp/0321714113) directly. It is recommended in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/388282/2985951) highly upvoted answer.

Comment: @n.m. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/operator_bool/ agrees.

Comment: As does the standard... "`explicit operator bool() const;` *Returns:* `!fail()`."

Comment: I added quote block formatting to the question. Please verify I didn't mess anything up.

Comment: @hobbs sorry my mistake.

Comment: @n.m. not a problem :)

Comment: @hyde The question looks good to me. Thanks for the edit :).

Comment: The *first* quote is wrong. That is, `eofbit` doesn't play a role in either `fail()` or `operator bool()`. The mistake is probably due to the fact that eofbit is often (but bu no means always) is set together with failbit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second and third statements are correct and in agreement with the C++ standard. The first one, then, is simply a mistake. Neither `fail` nor `operator bool` nor `operator !` take into account the `eofbit` state of a stream. Only `good` and `eof` do.

In the usual course of events, trying to read past the end of the stream sets both the `eofbit` and `failbit`, which is one likely reason why this mistake was so easy to make.

Comment: If `operator bool` does not check eof, then why does [this](https://pastebin.com/gRERFBiS) program seem to exit the while loop when typing ctrl+d on a Linux system? Does ctrl+d also invalidate stdin?

Comment: Because when it doesn't have any more characters to extract it sets the `failbit`. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt2

Comment: See the second paragraph of my answer — the attempt to read using `>>` after EOF causes the stream to be failed *as well as* EOF, so the boolean check returns false.